# Is there any way to make sure my function to be the last function to be called?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have overridden the global `new/delete` to catch memory leak. When the process exits, I need to call `assertNoMemoryLeak` to assert all the allocated memory by new has been released.

But it seems I cannot make `assertNoMemoryLeak` to be the last function called in my process, because some global variable destructor will be the last.

1. `atexit` doesn't work, for the following reason. AFAIK, the global destructor generated by gcc will be pushed to `atexit` list when the constructor is called, and I also cannot make my push 'assertNoMemoryLeak' snippet run before that during startup, so my `assertNoMemoryLeak` will still not run as the last function.
2. Another work around way is to write the `new/delete` info to file, and then after the process exit, analyze the file (using a script). I don't want to do it this way because it is complex to automatically do it for each developer.

So any way to make `assertNoMemoryLeak` the last function called?

Comment: I've removed the C++ tag, since this question is clearly not about C.

Comment: Not an answer, but why not use Valgrind to [detect memory leaks](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.leaks) instead?

Comment: Not really an answer, but can you get rid of your global variables? They're rarely a good idea.

Comment: @Mike Seymour, Global variable are arguable, right? I never know any C++ project which doesn't have global variable, including static/singleton object.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, the code will be run on Android. And the code run under Valgrind is too slow.

Comment: @TimothyJones, I think this is related to C++. Because global object constrcutor/destructor call order is defined by C++ standard.

Comment: If you have only one translation unit, you can make a global object that is constructed before every other global object, and have it call `atexit()` in the constructor, in which case the standard guarantees that the registered function will not be called until after all global objects are destroyed. With multiple translation units, you are out of luck, though.

Comment: @T.C. I surely working on an large project with thousands of translate unit.

Comment: I suppose you could use `at_quick_exit/quick_exit` to catch memory leaks in non-global variables (remember how many bytes were already allocated at start of `main` and compare that with what remains allocated at the end), but other than that I can't think of any standard compliant way to do what you want.

Comment: If you are using GCC, however, you can use the [`init_priority` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/C_002b_002b-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007binit_005fpriority_007d-attribute-3819) to force your `atexit`-registering object to be initialized first, but that [requires linker support](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2011-05/msg00221.html) so may not work for android.

Comment: @T.C.: "have it call `atexit()` in the constructor" - or, more simply, do the work in the destructor.

Comment: @T.C. Seams there is no perfect way to do that. So if you can make it as an answer, I will mark it as the best one.

Comment: @ZijingWu: Sorry, typo in my comment. I meant "I've removed the C tag".

Answer (score 0):

If finding and managing all the global static objects is practical, then you can make one global static object whose job it is to construct and destruct all other global objects in the desired order.  If you don't have control over all of them, or they are in too many different places in different libraries, this will not be practical.

You can do this by changing all global static objects to pointers, or by making them members of the one master object, or rewriting the code without global objects.  The point is eliminate anything that has startup and shutdown that you don't control, then run your assert checks at the proper time in the destructor of this one global object which you do control.

Comment: If you make global pointers, you can avoid changing other code by defining the old name as a reference to the dereferenced pointer, assuming the master startup object initialized that pointer correctly before any other code uses it.